# Subset of Unordered Pairs of Distinct Primary Keys With Normalization

Tags: database-design, mariadb-10.3

I am currently in the process of designing a database. I have one table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Set (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- other values
);
```

Now I wish to create another table that will store unordered pairs of distinct primary keys from the `Set` table, without sacrificing normalization. My first idea was:

```
CREATE TABLE Pairs (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    valueone INT NOT NULL,
    valuetwo INT NOT NULL,
    -- Appropriate foreign key constraints for valueone and valuetwo
);
```

But this has the problem that I could store, for example the pair `valueone=1, valuetwo=1` which I do not want as they are not distinct, or I could store either both or just one of `valueone=1, valuetwo=2` and `valuetwo=2,valueone=1` which (depending on how I interpret the data) would clearly be de-normalized. What is a natural, normalized way to store this fairly simple piece of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce, that `valueone < valuetwo`. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support check constraints with which this would be easy (You can define them, but they have no effect). You'd have to use triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pairs_bi
               BEFORE INSERT
                      ON pairs
               FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
  IF new.valueone >= new.valuetwo THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'valueone >= valuetwo';
  END IF;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER pairs_bu
               BEFORE UPDATE
                      ON pairs
               FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
  IF new.valueone >= new.valuetwo THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'valueone >= valuetwo';
  END IF;
END;
```

To enforce uniqueness you can then use a unique constraint/index or, if it where me, I'd simply define the two columns as primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE pairs
            DROP id;

ALTER TABLE pairs
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (valueone,
                             valuetwo);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b58ec4c5ea974376ab91898332db860)

Comment: For various reasons, I need the primary key so I will be including a unique constraint. However, on the upside, I am using MariaDB which has recently started enforcing check constraints. Thank you anyway for this very helpful answer!

Comment: Fortunately, now MySQL does support & enforce check constrains. Starting in version 8.0.16